# How to get associated values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, meteor, dom-events

I am reading a JSON file and adding a list with its element in a menu button in the browser, then I would like to get the values from the element that I have selected in the drop down list, so I am trying something like this below but it returns:

> "TypeError: selectedArray.values is not a function".

```
json = require('/myjsonFile');
event = json['foo']['bar'][0]['fooBar'];
var array = event.map( item => Object.keys(item) );

Template.board.helpers({
    'categories': function() {
        return array;
    }
});

Template.board.events({
    "change #category-select": function(event, template) {
        var selectedArray = $( event.currentTarget ).val();
        var data = selectedArray.values();
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working', what do you get? Also what is the value that you are trying to retrieve (add a sample)? edit your question then people would be able to help, otherwise it is not that clear.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated code and question, hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: If you add this line `console.log(selectedArray)` before `var data = selectedArray.values()` what do you get?

Comment: TypeError: selectedArray.values is not a function

Comment: That;s what you get if you use it before `selecetedArray.values()`?

Comment: Yeap,  ` "change #category-select": function(event, template) {
            var selectedArray = $( event.currentTarget ).val();
            console.log(selectedArray);
            var data = selectedArray.values();
        } `

Comment: But then you get the `TypeError` for the last line, nothing before that? If so remove the `selectedArray.values()` line, and see what you get. What is the value of the field you are trying to get?

Comment: Okay, I deleted the last line now turns this pt,eta,phi,m which is correct, but these have values (i.e., "phi":0.1, "eta":0.3 etc.), which I am trying to retrieve and use these values as array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159750/discussion-between-cowcrazy-and-user328693).